# SQLMap not matching string in response

Tags: sql, sql-injection, penetration-testing, sqlmap, penetration-tools

I'm using SQLMap for test SQL Injections on a login form, when the server validates credentials it returns an HTTP 200 Status Code and in the response body: `{"code":1}` (on valid credentials) or `{"code":0}` (on invalid credentials).

Since the status code is always 200 I need SQLMap to look for that string in the body, I found the following parameter:

> --string=STRING String to match when query is evaluated to True)

I'm using it like this:
`sqlmap -u https://example.com/login --method="POST" --data "user=1&password=2" --text-only --string='{"code":0}' -v 6`

But when SQLMap receives `{"code":1}` from the server just ignores it instead of detecting it as a successful injection.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or any ideas of how can I match that string in the response?

Here is the full server response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
Content-Length: 15
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

{"code":0}
```

Thanks in advance.